# Enviar id a script por ajax dependiendo del boton que se elija

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando enviar correos a ciertas personas dependiendo del boton que se elija, la tabla en la interfaz consta de dos campos, el nombre de la persona y el boton que al dar click se le va a enviar el correo.

Esta tabla la construyo por medio de un loop de un array sacado de base de datos previamente que contiene los ids de las personas.

```
echo '<legend>Enviar correos</legend>';
echo '<table>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.ucwords(getNameEmp($row['employee'])).'</td>';
                echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="send" value="'.$row['employee'].'" id="send"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Y mi petición de ajax es esta:

```
      $("#send").click('submit',(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "sendMails.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  { 
                    id: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }));
```

Mi pregunta es, cual es la mejor forma de saber que boton se seleccionó para saber que persona se le tiene que enviar el correo?

Comment: Este es el id $row['employee'] ??

Comment: No pongas val en un button utiliza un atributo asi: `data-id=" '.$row['employee'].' "` y en ajax lo cargas asi: `$(this).attr('data-id')`

Comment: En cuanto al boton aplicale una clase, por ejemplo `class="email"` y le aplicas esto: `$(".email").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
echo '<legend>Enviar correos</legend>';
echo '<table>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.ucwords(getNameEmp($row['employee'])).'</td>';
                echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default email" name="send" data-id="'.$row['employee'].'" id="send"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Luego en ajax:

```
$(".email").click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "sendMails.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  { 
                    id: $(this).attr('data-id')
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }));
```

Al boton le agregue la clase email como selector para jquery y ajax y en ajax cambie el selector y agrege la toma del id de esta manera: `$(this).attr('data-id')`

Comment: Me sirvió gracias

Answer (score 2):

Es incorrecto utilizar el mismo id, ya que solo debería ser único. En tu caso cada fila tiene el mismo id, "send", y no se puede identificar que boton es el que envia.

Sugiero que borres la parte de **id="send"**.

Por otra parte, el javascript debe localizar cada boton independientemente. Te recomiendo que cambies el javascript por:

```
   $("[name='send']").click('submit',(function(e) {
            value = $this.value();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "sendMails.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  { 
                    id: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }));
```

Te he cambiado el selector para que busque todos los que tengan como atributo name el valor send (en tu caso todos los button). Por otra parte, el value sera el $this (el boton que has pulsado) y .value().